# No result when Pagination with Servlet and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pagination, paging

I was trying to paging my product list into several pages. Each page contains 12 records. I used servlet to retrieve data from jsp file and JSTL to display data in JSP file. But my jsp file cant display anything. The main problem seems to be with "productList" not being available to the jsp
This is my servlet.

```
public class ProductServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    public ProductServlet(){
        super();
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        int page=1;
        int rowsPerPage=12;
            if (request.getParameter("page") != null) {
                page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
            }
            ProductDAO pd = new ProductDAO();
            List<Product> list = pd.getAllPaging((page - 1) * rowsPerPage, rowsPerPage);
            int noOfRows = list.size();
            int noOfPages = noOfRows / rowsPerPage;
            request.setAttribute("productList", list);
            request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
            request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("productlist.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my productlist.jsp file.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Game ID</th>
        <th>Game name</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>Realease date</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${product.gameid}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${product.gamename}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${product.price}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${product.releasedate}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<%--For displaying Previous link except for the 1st page --%>
<c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
    <td><a href="productlist.jsp?page=${currentPage - 1}">Previous</a></td>
</c:if>

<%--For displaying Page numbers. 
The when condition does not display a link for the current page--%>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
                    <td>${i}</td>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <td><a href="productlist.jsp?page=${i}">${i}</a></td>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And finally, my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProductServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>product.ProductServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProductServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/productlist</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I debugged my method getAllPaging() and it works perfectly, I checked and rechecked my jsp with JSTL syntax. It's ok. So I think the problem belongs to my servlet but I cant figure out what it is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the content of your page empty? or it is just the table that is empty? Can you confirm that your have data in your list? Do you have any error?

Comment: Yes I do have data on my list. I tried to print out the list from the method getAllPaging() and it works well.

Comment: And what is the content of your page after rendering? you just said it can't display... do you have error?

Comment: @RPresle thank you for replying me :), this is what I got after rendering the page http://i.imgur.com/C7NVraO.png . And I dont see any error report from my compiler which I use IntelliJ.

Comment: How did you import the tag library?

Comment: I put the jstl-1.2.jar in my project/web/WEB-INF/lib and I also import by using File>Project Structure>Project Settings>Libraries like this http://i.imgur.com/4mu4ERA.png

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant, how do you import your tag in your jsp file? I expect this kind of thing: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Comment: Yes I do declare that in my jsp file.

Comment: Could you print on your jsp page 1/ the content of `${productList.size}` 2/ do a `<c:forEach var="entry" begin="1" end="10">
 ${entry}, 
</c:forEach>`. These will allow us to check the content of you productList on jsp side and assure that the tag library is functional. Please show me conresponding code and result. Thks